# What is the result of this endgame?

Tags: rook-endgame

Can Black draw this position or does White win after all:

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "8/P4R2/8/6kp/3K4/6P1/r7/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

I need variations that clearly illustrate your answer.

Comment: Houdini wins it at Level 21 Ply and Level 23 Ply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White has a very simple strategy to win this position -

1. **Prevent the g-pawn from being captured for free by the Black king** (the Black rook cannot capture it because it is tied to the defense of the **a-pawn** promoting on **a8**. White wins if White can win the **h-pawn**)
2. Move the White king over to support the promotion of the **a-pawn**.
3. At the right moment, occupy the **b-file** with the White rook and support the **g-pawn** from **b3**. Then White's king can have a safe square on the **b-file** to promote the **a-pawn**.

   ```
    [FEN "8/5R2/P7/6kp/3K4/6P1/r7/8 w - - 0 1"]

    1. a7 Kg4 (1... Kg6 2. Rc7 Ra5 3. Kc4 Kf6 4. Kb4 Ra1 5. Kc5 Ke6 6. Rh7 Rc1+ 7.
    Kb6 Rb1+ 8. Ka6 Ra1+ 9. Kb7 Rb1+ 10. Kc8 Rc1+ 11. Kb8 Rb1+ 12. Rb7 Ra1 13. a8=Q
    ) 2. Rg7+ Kh3 3. Kc3 Kg2 4. Kb4 Kh3 5. Kb5 Ra3 (5... Rxa7 6. Rxa7 Kxg3 7. Rg7+
    Kf3 (7... Kh3 8. Kc4 h4 9. Kd3 Kh2 10. Ke2 h3 11. Kf2 Kh1 12. Rg1+ Kh2 13. Rg3
    Kh1 14. Rxh3#) 8. Rh7 Kg4 9. Kc4 h4 10. Kd3 Kg3 11. Ke2 h3 12. Kf1 h2 13. Rh6
    Kg4 14. Rxh2)6. Kb6 Rb3+ 7. Ka6 Ra3+ 8. Kb7
    Rb3+ 9. Ka8 Rb5 (9... Rb2 10. Rg5 Rb1 11. Rxh5+ Kxg3 12. Rh8 Kf4 13. Rb8 Ra1
    14. Kb7 Rb1+ 15. Kc7 Rc1+ 16. Kd7 Rd1+ 17. Ke7 Re1+ 18. Kf7 Ra1 19. a8=Q) 10.
    Rb7 Ra5 11. Rb3! Kg4 12. Kb8 Ra2 13. a8=Q
   ```

Comment: You should also give the variation when black sacrifices the rook with the white king furthest away from the `h`-pawn. (`5... Rxa7`)

Comment: I was thinking about something else for Black, more along the lines of `1...Ra5!?` so he can actually try and hold the game... Still, I have upvoted because of your thorough coverage.